# Python Script generates 500 Internal Server Error but code in different file works fine

Tags: python, vps

I have a Python script with the following code:

```
#! /home/flohosting/PythonTest/PythonTest/bin/python

print()
print("hello world!")
```

I'm running Python 3.6 on a GoDaddy VPS.  The Python 3.6 is a virtual environment.  This script works just fine.  The problem arises when in Virtual Studio Code I open a new document, copy the code above from the working .py script and then paste it into the new .py script, upload the script, CHMOD to 755, and try to execute.  Then I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  It makes no sense to me.

I've logged into my SSH with PuTTY and tried to CHMOD a+x file_name.py  where "file_name" is the exact filename and it still doesn't work.  I can't think of anything else to even check to see why the script works in a file that's been on the server for 2+ months and not in a new script I upload and CHMOD to 755.  Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:  the link to the script working is http://www.dockethound.com/bernard.py

The link to the non-working script is http://www.dockethound.com/hello.py

EDIT 2:  I figured something out and it is working though I have no idea why.

When using CuteFTP 9, I upload on "AUTO".  I decided to select ASCII and then try uploading again.  When I uploaded I got an error that said "This appears to be a binary file you want to upload with ASCII.  Are you sure?" So for some reason the file is being saved in a binary format or something that CuteFTP recognizes as a binary format and is uploading it in binary which causes Apache issues when trying to run it.  BUT if it's uploaded in forced ASCII mode, the problems are solved.

Jarod

Comment: The output of a Web program has to begin with a `Content-type` line.  If it doesn't, you get a 500 server error.  Try adding `print("Content-type: text/plain")` as the first line.

Comment: Can you look at the server side logs?  Maybe that has more information about the issue.  Plus, it's not clear how the above script and what you're doing on the server are related since the script above has nothing to do with serving web data.

Comment: If you're using CGI @JohnGordon has a great point.

Comment: John - it doesn't have to begin with that as the script at www.dockethound.com/bernard.py works just fine.  The exact same script at www.dockethound.com/hello.py doesn't work at all.

Comment: And `bernard.py` has the same contents as `hello.py`?  Perhaps it's a web server configuration issue then.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same, copied and pasted.  The only difference (that I see) is that bernard.py has been on the server for awhile and obviously the new script hasn't. To answer the question about the error_log....the error_log text file doesn't show anything about the error being thrown here. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Just an FYI, when responding to comments on your question, make sure to reference the person via @username, otherwise they don't get notification of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, using the Auto setting in CuteFTP 9 allowed CuteFTP to determine that the file types with .py were binary files so the files were transferred via binary and not ASCII.  Forcing ASCII fixed the problem, then going into TOOLS->Global Options->ASCII types and adding PY to the list fixed the problem.

Comment: So it sounds like this is not actually the problem, but your end of line characters are the issue.  If you change the file to use "LF" endings, I bet your problem goes away even in BINARY mode.

Comment: @John Szakmeister - Thanks. I'll be searching now how to change to use LF endings in Visual Studio Code.